# Как сделать, чтобы по клику на чекбокс ничего не происходило?

Tags: javascript, html

Как disabled, только вид нормальный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
$('checkbox').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); или return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = document.getElementById("my_checkbox");
c.onchange = function(){
  this.checked = !this.checked;
}
```